# Recaptcha unreachable Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

I have contact form and sendcontact action respon with js, before use `reCaptcha` gem, send contact is works.

- gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails'
- public and private key
- recaptcha.rb

> ```
> Recaptcha.configure do |config|
>   config.public_key  = '6LcPi-zzzzzzzzz'
>   config.private_key = '6LcPi-xxxxxxxxx'
>   config.proxy = 'http://localhost:3000/'
> end
> ```

Here's form and controller

```
  # contact form

  <%= form_for Contact.new, :url => { :action => "sendcontact" }, :remote => true  do |f| %> 
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :email %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :email %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :message %><br />
   <%= f.text_area :message, :style => 'height:200px;width:300px;resize:vertical;' %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
    <%= recaptcha_tags %>
 </div>
 <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Send", :class => 'btn btn-success btn-large' %>
 </div>
 <% end %>

 #controller

 def sendcontact
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    if verify_recaptcha
       @contact.save!
       respond_to do |format|
         flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you for contacting me'
         format.js
       end
    else
       respond_to do |format|
         format.js
       end
    end
  end
```

when submit form, always display notice `Recaptcha unreachable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved

Just remove `config.proxy = 'http://localhost:3000/'`

because I'm not using proxy and `http://localhost:3000/` is not proxy so verify captcha not send to server google and show up an alert "recaptcha unreachable"

"Recaptcha Unreachable" show when timeout is over.

Here's  rescue Timeout::Error https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/blob/master/lib/recaptcha/verify.rb#L53

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on why and how that solved the problem so future users will benefit from this answer?